# How do you cancel a travis (or other ci) build based on sauce labs usage?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, travis-ci, saucelabs

Let me start off by saying that our team is small, and this is what we need based on budgeting, etc.

Sauce Labs does not give us the ability to turn off automated testing, let alone automatically. This can result in overage charges if we exceed X hours in a month, billed per minute. My boss approves that lump sum at the beginning of the year, but not overages.

I know that there are APIs for usage: https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Test+Activity+and+Usage+Methods

But I have no idea where to start to query/parse that information into a usable exit/failure to prevent a build from proceeding.

Any help is much appreciated... Thanks!

Comment: How is this question related to `Selenium`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I've setup billing alarms with [aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html), do they provide something similar? I can see they have an [API](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/The+Sauce+Labs+REST+API), maybe check with [selenium slack](https://seleniumhq.herokuapp.com) as they have a sauce labs channel.

Comment: @lloyd They don’t have alarms or anything, I think it’s part of their business model. I’m curious if anyone has attempted this before I attempt to figure out what the heck these values from the API mean. I might just try running a node script to do it all.

Comment: [easy-sauce](https://github.com/philipwalton/easy-sauce) might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a script that will do this!
Free for use by anyone.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/expired-sauce